# How to check for certain chars in a line of text in c

Tags: c

I have this code for a school project, and I have 2 questions. first one is my code crashes after the second loop through, right after "enter the phrase to be converted."

My second question is, I need to add a section that, if the any words in str begin with a vowel, end them with -way and keeps the first letter. EX apple = appleway, but if it is not a vowel; run piglatinwork()

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
//calls and functon prototypes
int printlatinwork (char *thiss);
int main ()
{
    char again;

    do {
        char *thiss;
        char str[20];
        /* prompt the user to enter his phrase */
        printf ("please enter the phrase to be converted\n");
        str[20] = gets (str);

        /*  THIS LOOPS THRU TOKENS AND PRINTS */
        thiss = strtok (str, " ");
        if (thiss != NULL);
        {
            printlatinwork (thiss);
            thiss = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }

        printf ("\ngo again? enter y to go again\n");
        scanf ("%c", &again);

    } while (again == 'y');

    return 0;
}

/*  FUNCTION TO PRINT, CALLED THERE */
printlatinwork (char *thiss)
{
    printf ("%s%c%s ", thiss + 1, thiss[0], "ay");
    return;
}
```

Comment: `str[20]` is beyond the end of the array (`str[0]` to `str[19]` are the valid array entries), so you have undefined behavior. You should be checking the return value of `gets` for NULL, but there's no need to assign the return value to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a mess. First do NOT use `gets`. It is no longer part of libc and is horribly insecure. Next, you cannot assign a string with `=` after the initial declaration and initialization. It is also a good idea to **always** initialize **all** of your variables. (attempting to read/use an uninitialized value is **Undefined Behavior**)

There are a number of ways to use `strtok`. One of the most effective is simply to use a `for` loop. The initial condition uses the name of the string variable, while the increment uses `NULL`. The test condition is simply that the return is not `NULL`. When using `strtok` it will destroy the original string (by embedding `null-terminating` characters in it). While not required in your code, it is a good idea to always send a copy to `strtok`. (it is imperative if `str` is dynamically allocated) Also, **note:** the return from `strtok` (a pointer to the current token), is **only good** for the current iteration. If you need to preserve the token, make a copy of it as well.

Next, when you compile your program, always compile with **warnings** enabled. At minimum `gcc -Wall -o progname yourfile.c`. You can also add `-Wextra`.

Here is an updated version of your code. Take a look and let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 256

/* calls and functon prototypes */
void printlatinwork (char *thiss);

int main (void)
{
    char again = 'n';

    do {
        char *thiss = 0;
        char str[MAXS] = {0};
        char copy[MAXS] = {0};
        size_t nchr = 0;
        int c = 0;

        /* prompt the user to enter his phrase */
        printf ("please enter the phrase to be converted: ");
        // str[20] = gets (str); /* NEVER USE gets */
        fgets (str, MAXS - 1, stdin);

        /* get the length of str */
        nchr = strlen (str);

        /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */
        while (nchr > 0 && (str[nchr-1] == '\n' || str[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            str[--nchr] = 0;

        /* strtok destroys original string, make copy */
        strncpy (copy, str, strlen (str));

        /*  THIS LOOPS THRU TOKENS AND PRINTS */
        for (thiss = strtok (copy, " "); thiss != NULL; thiss = strtok (NULL, " "))
            printlatinwork (thiss);

        printf ("\ngo again? enter y to go again\n");
        scanf ("%c", &again);

        /* always flush the input buffer after calling scanf
           or craft a format string that consumes the newline
           that remains in stdin (created by pressing [Enter]) */
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    } while (again == 'y');

    return 0;
}

/*  FUNCTION TO PRINT, CALLED THERE */
void printlatinwork (char *thiss)
{
    printf ("%s%c%s ", thiss + 1, thiss[0], "ay");
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/findchar
please enter the phrase to be converted: this is my phrase
histay siay ymay hrasepay
go again? enter y to go again
y
please enter the phrase to be converted: this is my phrase
histay siay ymay hrasepay
go again? enter y to go again
n
```

**Note** in `printlatinwork` you should check the length of `thiss` is greater than `1` to prevent an **undefined read past end of string** (bad).

Comment: thanks, our teacher informed us that gets() is unstable, but we can use it in some scenarios. As this is still an intro level course, I am unfamiliar with some code you used. I corrected some code with the explanations of my errors, and it looks like it is working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. You've made the right choice to learn C. Nothing provides you with the control that C does. But with great power comes great responsibility. Coding is all about operating on memory, but at that level, it's either right or bad things happen. Enjoy learning C -- it's a journey, not a race...